# Speed up double for loop in report generation. maybe with lists?

Tags: r, simulation

Hello I have a simulation that runs pretty fast below. What I am having trouble with is speeding up the reporting that is happening on the data generated by the simulation.

```
#Load in relevant libraries
library(splitstackshape)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#sample data for simulation

set.seed(100)
input <- data.frame(JobNum = seq(1:200)
    ,HangsPerWeek = sample(1:50, 200,replace=T)
    ,DS.CT = sample(c(38,41,43),200,replace=T)
    ,C1.CT = sample(c(40,41,42),200,replace=T)
    ,C2.CT = sample(c(36,41),200,replace=T)
    ,C3.CT = sample(c(38,39,40),200,replace=T)
    ,C4.CT = sample(c(40,27),200,replace=T)
    ,C5D5.CT = sample(c(20,21,22),200,replace=T)
    ,C6D6.CT = sample(c(20,21,22),200,replace=T)
    ,C5D7.CT = sample(c(20,21,22),200,replace=T)
    ,C6D8.CT = sample(c(9,22,23),200,replace=T)
    ,C7CD.CT = sample(c(40,41),200,replace=T))

input$JobNum<-as.character(input$JobNum)

#expand input file to have a single row per part
partsList<-expandRows(input, "HangsPerWeek")

#Set up cluster using all but one core on machine 
#this runs the simulation in parallel
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#Initialize variables
partsOrder <- list()
numSim <- 10

#start simulation
SimResults <- foreach(j=1:numSim) %dopar%{

RobotSimulation <- function(){

#randomize the dataset of parts and record the order
set.seed(100)
parts <- partsList[sample(nrow(partsList)),]
partsOrder <- list(parts$JobNum)

#choose a random sample of parts to populate the conveyor belts
#this random assignment will be constant across all iterations of the simulation
set.seed(101)
LineParts <- partsList[sample(nrow(partsList),234,replace=FALSE),]

#pass parts through system one at a time and record cycle times at each dip
LineParts_dfList <- lapply(seq(nrow(parts)), function(i){      
    #Index line
    LinePartsTemp <- parts[1,]
    LinePartsTemp[2:nrow(LineParts),] <- LineParts[1:nrow(LineParts)-1,]

    #put new part into system
    LinePartsTemp[1,] <- parts[i,]

    #update the list of parts on the line
    LineParts <<- LinePartsTemp      
})

otherstations_veclist <- 
  list(
    DS = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[1,'DS.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D1 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[10,'C1.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D2 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[26,'C2.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D3 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[42,'C3.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D4 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[57,'C4.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D5 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[85,'C5D5.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D6 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[120,'C6D6.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D7 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[167,'C5D7.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D8 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[210,'C6D8.CT'], numeric(1)),
    D9 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[216,'C7CD.CT'], numeric(1))
  )

jobstations_veclist <- 
  list(
    DS = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[1,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D1 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[10,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D2 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[26,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D3 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[42,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D4 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[57,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D5 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[85,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D6 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[120,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D7 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[167,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D8 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[210,'JobNum'], character(1)),
    D9 = vapply(LineParts_dfList, function(df) df[216,'JobNum'], character(1))
  )

#record results
result <- list(partsOrder = partsOrder, CT = otherstations_veclist, JobNum = jobstations_veclist)
return(result)
}

RobotSimulation()

}

#stop using all cores
stopCluster(cl)
```

After this runs I am creating 4 different graphs with a double for loop to go through each iteration of the simulation. Is there a way to keep using the lists in R to speed up the calculations? or is the for loops the only option?

```
#For every time we add a new part to the line for every simulation 
#find the felt cycle time and the bottlenecks

ProblemJob <- c()
FeltCT <- c()
BottleNeck <- c()
CTs <- c()

for(s in 1:numSim){
  for(p in 1:dim(partsList)[1]){
    CT <- c(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[1]][[p]],
      SimResults[[s]][[2]][[2]][[p]],
      SimResults[[s]][[2]][[3]][[p]],
      SimResults[[s]][[2]][[4]][[p]],
      SimResults[[s]][[2]][[5]][[p]],
      max(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[6]][[p]],SimResults[[s]][[2]][[7]][[p]])+max(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[8]][[p]], SimResults[[s]][[2]][[9]][[p]]),
      SimResults[[s]][[2]][[10]][[p]]
    )
    FeltCT <- append(FeltCT,max(CT))
    BottleNeck <- append(BottleNeck,which(CT==max(CT)))
    CTs <- append(CTs,CT[which(CT==max(CT))])
    ProblemJob <- append(ProblemJob,if(which(CT==max(CT))==1){paste('DS',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[1]][[p]],sep=' ')}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==2){paste('R1',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[2]][[p]],sep=' ')}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==3){paste('R2',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[3]][[p]],sep=' ')}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==4){paste('R3',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[4]][[p]],sep=' ')}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==5){paste('R4',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[5]][[p]],sep=' ')}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==6){c(
                    if(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[6]][[p]] >= SimResults[[s]][[2]][[7]][[p]]){paste('R5D5',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[6]][[p]],sep=' ')}else{paste('R6D6',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[7]][[p]],sep=' ')}
                    ,if(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[8]][[p]] >= SimResults[[s]][[2]][[9]][[p]]){paste('R5D7',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[8]][[p]],sep=' ')}else{paste('R6D8',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[9]][[p]],sep=' ')}
                    ,paste(if(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[6]][[p]] >= SimResults[[s]][[2]][[7]][[p]]){SimResults[[s]][[3]][[6]][[p]]}else{SimResults[[s]][[3]][[7]][[p]]},
                        if(SimResults[[s]][[2]][[8]][[p]] >= SimResults[[s]][[2]][[9]][[p]]){SimResults[[s]][[3]][[8]][[p]]}else{SimResults[[s]][[3]][[9]][[p]]},sep='/')
                    )}
    else if(which(CT==max(CT))==7){paste('R7',SimResults[[s]][[3]][[10]][[p]],sep=' ')}
      )
  }
}

BottleNeckPercent <- 100*tabulate(BottleNeck)/length(BottleNeck)
RobotAvg<-aggregate(CTs~BottleNeck,FUN=mean)
base <- data.frame(BottleNeck=seq(1:7),CTs=rep(0,7))
RobotAvg <- merge(base,RobotAvg,by='BottleNeck',all=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
bp <- barplot(RobotAvg$CTs.y,
    names.arg=c('DS','R1','R2','R3','R4','R5/R6','R7'),
    col="lightblue",
    main="Average Cycle Time per Robot",
    xlab="Robot",ylab="Seconds")
text(bp,RobotAvg$CTs.y,round(RobotAvg$CTs.y),pos=1)

hist(FeltCT,col='yellow',main=paste('Avg Cycle Time:',round(mean(FeltCT),1),sep=' '))

barplot(head(table(ProblemJob)[order(-table(ProblemJob))],20),las=2,col='red',main='Top 20 Problem Jobs and Location')
bp2<-barplot(BottleNeckPercent
    ,col='green'
    ,names=c('DS','R1','R2','R3','R4','R5/R6','R7')
    ,main='% Cause of Bottleneck'
    ,xlab='Robot'
    ,ylab='%')

text(bp2,BottleNeckPercent,paste(round(BottleNeckPercent,2),'%',sep=''),pos=1)
```

The results look like this:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is intentional but at present your code gives a number of warnings which arise from the `if(which(CT == max(CT)) == 1)` type statements since `which(x == max(x))` can return more than one index which then leads to multiple logicals in your if statement, the first of which is the only one which gets checked. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Hello, I wanted to capture information on all ties. If you look at length(ProblemJob) it is larger than length(FeltCT). I thought that was evidence that all ties were being processed. is that not the case? Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: It is longer because of `if(which(CT == max(CT)) == 6)` where you then combine a number of `paste` calls, I don't think you are dealing with the ties here in the way that you think you are. One quick way to solve this would be to change from `if(which(CT == max(CT)) == i)` to `if(i %in% which(CT == max(CT)))` but it won't help with the efficiency as per OP. I am working on that bit. excluding the problem job I have got it down to about 1/20th the time for the other bits

Comment: I'm also slightly confused by the step appending ProblemJob where you have two if statements checking the same condition when `... == 6`. In one you `paste("R...")` the other you don't. Is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry ignore most recent comment, I see now

Comment: yes, so 6 is a special point in the simulation where multiple things are happening. This is a station where two robots are interacting. The first part of the statement looks for which robot in the pair is causing the bottleneck the second part gives the combination with a / in between. I haven't analyzed the interaction data with the / yet. My intent was to see maybe if there was certain pairs that always showed up together. but it didn't look like it in my real data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I thought my initial thoughts were it wouldn't be too hard to achieve what you wanted and this would be a quick one before I head for dinner. Not so much, I am still not happy with the solution, but it's mainly the `ProblemJob` variable that is making it painful. My solution by timing on my laptop gives me approx 1.5 - 1.7 seconds for my solution against 36-39 seconds for your current solution. I am sure it could be made more efficient but I need to eat now. My answers give all the same as yours with the exception of `ProblemJob` as discussed in comments on OP. Any way without further ado:

One of the things that was slowing you down was appending to vectors everywhere in the double loop. Removing that would make a huge difference. The problem is for some of the variables you don't know ahead of time how many results there will be to preallocate. However there is a lot of the computations that you do here using `lapply` on lists and `purrr::pmap` function. There were also a few places where you compute the same thing multiple times.

We can precompute all of the `CT` iterations in one go which gives us one less thing in the nested iteration structure as well as create all of the labels that might be used for `ProblemJob`:

```
library(purrr)
simlist = transpose(SimResults)[[2]] %>% lapply(.,function(x) do.call(cbind,x))
labels = transpose(SimResults)[[3]] %>% lapply(.,function(x) do.call(cbind,x))
CT_list = lapply(simlist, function(x) cbind(x[,1:5], pmax(x[,6],x[,7]) + pmax(x[,8],x[,9]),x[,10,drop = FALSE]))
bool1 = lapply(simlist, function(x) x[,6] > x[,7])
bool2 = lapply(simlist, function(x) x[,8] > x[,9])
special_labels = pmap(list(labels,bool1,bool2), function(x,y,z){
  paste(ifelse(y,x[,6],x[,7]), ifelse(z, x[,8],x[,9]),sep = "/")
})  

labels = lapply(labels, function(x) {
  x = t(x)
  x[] = paste(c("DS","R1","R2","R3","R4","R5D5", "R6D6","R5D7","R6D8","R7"), x)
  t(x)
  }
)
```

Since you were repeatedly pulling the second and third components out of the `SimResults` list it makes sense to use `purrr:transpose` to do this in one go, then `lapply` across the resultant list to give a nicer shape again. `pmax` here is part of Base R and is parallel max, essentially a vectorised `max` function.

Since the comparison operators are vectorised we can do this along the lists to create the boolean conditions that are being checked for `ProblemJob`. In terms of your original code here, the components of `simlist` are the 10 values of `s` in your loop, the rows of each component are the 5000+ values of `p` in your loop and the 10 columns are the values of `CT` that you calculate at each iteration. `ifelse` is a vectorised version of `if(...){} else {}`

Having precomputed all of that we now need to map over the lists, to create all of the output, this is the bit where your `ProblemJob` variable caused problems since I couldn't think of a neat way to remove the nested `lapply` on an empty stomach

```
out_list = pmap(list(CT_list, special_labels, labels, bool1, bool2), function(x,sl,z,b1,b2){
  lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i){
    y = x[i,]
    m = max(y)
    ix = which(y == m)
    # only need to do something special when ix contains a 6
    if(6 %in% ix){
     temp1 = ifelse(b1[i],z[i,6], z[i,7])  
     temp2 = ifelse(b2[i], z[i,8],z[i,9])
     lab = c(temp1,temp2,sl[i], z[i,ix[ix != 6]])
    }else{
      lab = z[i,ix]
    }
    list(FeltCT = m, BottleNeck = ix, CTs = y[ix], ProblemJob = lab)
  }) %>% transpose %>% simplify_all()
}) %>% transpose %>% simplify_all()
```

We are using `transpose %>% simplify_all()` here from `purrr` to essentially join the same named components back up in the resultant lists of lists. You can check that for the 3 variables you get the same solutions by pulling the results out of `out_list`

```
all(out_list$FeltCT == FeltCT)
all(out_list$BottleNeck == BottleNeck)
all(out_list$CTs == CTs)
```

Not entirely happy with using `lapply` inside `pmap` here but hope it helps, it's certainly faster than the original by a fair whack. I need dinner now.

Comment: I wish I could give you more reputation than an up-vote and a check mark. Excellent job!